# How can I get 2nd digit of a number manually

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = 234;

    // Gets first digit
    int digit = n / 100;
    putchar('0' + digit);

    // gets 3rd digit
    digit = n % 10;
    putchar('0' + digit);


}
```

How can I get "3" aka 2nd digit?

Also
If the n was something like 245836 how could I extract each digit one by one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by dividing by ten and then taking the remainder of division by ten:

```
int second = (number / 10) % 10;
```

In general, you could think of integer-dividing by a `k`-th power of ten as of *dropping* `k` least significant digits. Taking a remainder of division by `k`-th power of ten is equivalent to *keeping* the last `k` digits.

> how could I extract each digit one by one?

You can take the last digit with `%10` and then dropping that digit off the end by `/= 10`.

Comment: That's the second digit from the right. I think he is asking for the second digit from the left .  (of course that's the same for a 3-digit number but in general it is different).

Answer (score 2):

As an expansion on the answer you already got: In general, you can get the `i`th digit from the right with:

```
int digit = (n / (int) pow(10, i)) % 10;
```

where `i` is a zero-based index. You can get the index of the most significant digit with `i = log10(n)` and loop your way down to 0. `pow` and `log10` are floating-point functions, which should be used carefully in integer calculations.

Alternatively, you can get at the powers of 10 in decreasing order by sequential division by 10 of an initial value `d`, which also must be a power of 10. You can find this value `d` by repeatedly multiplying 1 with 10 until the next multiplication would exceed your number.

Here's a simple program that prints all digits of a positive integer in order:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int n = 0;
    unsigned int d = 1;
    
    while (d <= n / 10) d *= 10;
    
    while (d) {
        unsigned int digit = (n / d) % 10;

        putchar('0' + digit);
        d /= 10;
    }
    
    putchar('\n');    
    return 0;
}
```

The example uses `unsigned int`, because it works only with non-negative numbers.

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple program to print a digit in tenth position.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{

     public static void main(String []args){
         int n;
         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         n=sc.nextInt();
         if(n>0)
         {
             n=n%100;
             n=n/10;
         }
        System.out.println(n);
     }
}
```

Comment: This is not a C answer, this is a Java answer. Downvoted.